# disabling submit button and enable if change was made to the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox and a submit button. I want to have the button grayed out (disabled) on pageload and when the user makes a change in the textbox whether adding text or removing text the button will be enabled and once it is saved the button will be disabled again.

```
<h3>Username</h3>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.username)

<button class="btn btn-small savebtn" type="submit" value="User Name">Save</button>
```

Now the issue i am having is how to properly insert this script into my view. This is my current view:

```
@model Project.Models.UsernameModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("_UsernamePartial", "Account")) {

   <h3>Username</h3>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Username)

<button class="btn btn-small savebtn" type="submit" value="User name">Save</button>
```

do i add the script like this at the bottom after the  tag:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".savebtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $("#UserName").keyup(function () {
            $(".savebtn").removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        $(".savebtn").click(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Calvin.Allen `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled","disabled");
}` but it is not graying out the button like how i want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Disable Save Button On Page Load
    $(".savebtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    //When User Name changes, enable Save Button
    $("#UserName").keyup(function() {
        $(".savebtn").removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    //Disable Save Button once clicked
    $(".savebtn").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

And here is a sample [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9C6CE/).

Comment: one more question if possible... I am not sure if i am adding this script properly on the view page. I've updated my question with more code above. Thanks again.

Comment: If you view the source of your rendered page in the browser, you should be able to tell if your javascript is being added correctly.